# Is it possible to change the service endpoint path on gateway using spring cloud

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a running api on my local machine with url http://localhost:8080/gnk-debt/service/taxpayer-debt.
And I would like this api to be available through gateway with url **http://localhost:8243/gnk/service/phystaxpayer/debt/v1**.
To do so, first I set the port in property file. But I am not able set custom url for the api endpoint. I am trying to write a simple gateway using spring cloud, configuration of which as following:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringCloudConfig {
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder)
{
    return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
            .route("gnkTaxpayerDebt", rt -> rt.path("/gnk-debt/**")
                    .uri("http://localhost:8080/"))
            .build();

}
}
```

But at the end, gateway api endpoint is available at: http://localhost:8243/gnk-debt/service/taxpayer-debt.

The question that I am curios about is that if it is possible to change gateway api endpoint to:
**http://localhost:8243/gnk/service/phystaxpayer/debt/v1**

**EDIT**

As [spencergibb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2730527/spencergibb) mentioned that there are some options to do that. I started with RewritePath, subsequently my config has been changed as following:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder)
{
return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
            .route("gnkTaxpayerDebt", rt -> rt.path("/gnk/**")
                    .filters(f->f.rewritePath("/gnk/service/phystaxpayer/debt/v1(?<remains>.*)","/${remains}"))
                    .uri("http://localhost:8080"))
            .build();

}
```

At the end I am able to access my gateway endpoint at
http://localhost:8243/gnk/service/phystaxpayer/debt/v1/**gnk-physicaltaxpayer-debt/gnk/service/physical-taxpayer-debt**

How can I change the final endpoint to: http://localhost:8243/gnk/service/phystaxpayer/debt/v1

Comment: There are a number of options, the SetPath, RewritePath and PrefixPath filters

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways of setting your own endpoint is to create a GlobalFilter where you change the attribute "GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR" that comes with ServerWebExchangeUtils. You just have to set your endpoint as below

```
exchange.getAttributes().put(GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, yourEndpoint);
```